# iFrames and Web Resources not displaying in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have created a simple HTML web resource to display some text and a static hyperlink.  When I insert the web resource into my form and then preview the form (Update Form), I see my web resource.  The text is there, and the hyperlink works great.  However, when I save and Publish All Customizations, I cannot get the web resource to show up on the form in any browser.  The same goes for an iFrame.  I see an iFrame in the preview, but it will not display after publishing it.  I get no errors and I can't seem to pinpoint where I am going wrong.  This is an on-premises CRM 2011 deployment.  Thanks in advance for any direction in troubleshooting.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I add a simple javascript test to the form, it also works in the preview but is completely ignored after I publish it.  I added a 'Hello World' alert, and then an event handler.  I see it in preview, but there is no trace of it after publishing.  However, when I make other changes to my form they appear instantly after publishing.

Comment: If you open the form in a debugger do you get any errors? Perhaps it's publishing with a different url?

Comment: When I open it with Firebug I don't get any errors.  It's like it isn't even there. When I make other changes and publish, it updates.  But when I add javascript or web resources and publish, I get nothing.  It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be path issue. 
To verify it you can go to Settings -> Customization -> Customize the system -> web resources -> click on your Iframe web resource -> Copy URL( `e.g. https://youronpremisesCRM//WebResources/new_IframeWebResource` )

Give this absolute path in Iframe source. It will work. After that give relative path like ( `/WebResources/new_IframeWebResource` ).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Unfortunately, the full URL is already in the iFrame source.  If I copy and paste it into the browser, the HTML web resource displays fine. And the iFrame shows up in preview, but I still can't get it to display after being published. I have to be missing something simple, but I've beat my head against the wall for days...